# How do I fix comments problem in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm do strange comments like `<!--       adress-->` with many spaces before open tag and comment word.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a proper example: 1) what code you had before, 2) what your did (pressed keys/command executed etc) 3) what you had as a result and 4) what you want to have instead. A code that can be copy-pasted and tested locally + a bunch of screenshot (or better a small video) that would better illustrate the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "do strange comments"? Does this mean that adding a new comment looks strange? That existing comments are shown in a strange way?

Comment: can be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52259/Cursor-position-is-wrong-on-inserting-single-line-comment-through-ctrl-in-HTML; see if it looks similar